# Codeigniter Delete from Database issue

Tags: php, forms, function, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter, I have managed to get insert working into the database and I have done the code to delete from the database however when clicking on the job to delete it, it just refreshes and the job is still in the database.

My Controller

```
public function deleteclientform(){
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->model("clientmodel"); 
    $data['clients']=$this->clientmodel->getallclients();
    $data['title']="Delete Job";
    $this->load->view("deleteclientform",$data); 
}

public function delete(){
    $films=$this->input->post('clients');
    $this->load->model("clientmodel");
    foreach($clients as $jobno)
    {
        $this->clientmodel->deleteclient($jobno);
    }
     redirect('/nav/home', 'refresh');
}
```

My Model

```
function deleteclient($jobno)

{
$this->db->where('jobno', $jobno);
$result=$this->db->delete('client');
return $result;
}
```

My View

```
echo form_open('client/delete');

foreach($clients as $client)
{
echo "<p>";
echo form_label($client->job, 'client'.$client->jobno);
$data = array('name' => 'clients[]', 'jobno'=>'client'.$client->jobno, 'value' =>    $client->jobno);
echo form_checkbox($data);
echo "</p>";
}
echo form_submit("delete_btn","Delete these Jobs");
echo form_close();
```

Comment: Where does `$clients` come from in your `controller`? `clients/delete`?

Comment: This, `foreach($clients as $jobno)` should be `foreach($films as $jobno)`

Answer (score 1):

```
public function delete(){
    $films=$this->input->post('clients');
    $this->load->model("clientmodel");
    foreach($films as $jobno)
              ^ this
    {
        $this->clientmodel->deleteclient($jobno);
    }
     redirect('/nav/home', 'refresh');
}
```

This function in your controller was wrong.

You were referring to `$clients` when it was `$films` you wanted.